# Failed to setup SSH FTP in Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, sftp, ubuntu-18.04

After i installed SSH, 
i try to configure Chroot, but then i got following error when i try to login.

Feb 29 11:53:49 tng-ubuntu sshd[15314]: error: /dev/pts/2: No such file or directory

Not very sure about what happen, i try many many options, actually almost spent a whole afternoon, still don't know what is the issue.

Can someone help?

Subsystem sftp  internal-sftp -l VERBOSE

Whenever i have following section in my sshd_config, it failed.
I already try to change /home to /home/%u or %h ...

Match Group sftponly
        ChrootDirectory /home
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -l VERBOSE

Comment: Please move your question to [su] or [sf] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user is NOT in the sftponly group for ssh access.

This problem happened to me when I added myself to the sftp group.

Remove users with ssh access from the sftponly group using this command...
deluser username sftponly

Answer (score -1):

Actually my configuration works, but i was verifying using SSH login, and my SSH failed to login. Though i still don't know why my SSH failed to login, but anyway, my SFTP works.
Need to check further why the SSH failed to login.